# STM32F4 SPI idle time between each data frame, why is it too long?

Tags: arm, stm32, spi, cortex-m

I am trying to read 256 bits in less than 32 ms from SPI, the data frame is 16 bits. My problem here is SPI driver has a long idle time between each 16 bits. See this [picture](https://ibb.co/niQKqJ), as you can see I am reading 64 bits (highlighted by the red rectangle), and there are long pauses between each frame. I don't find anything in the SPI specification about it.

I am testing on an STM32F407 board from Keil and SPI is initialized by the Keil CMSIS default driver.

Is there any way to reduce this idle time?

Comment: Why the `m4` tag?

Comment: How are you transferring the data? Polling tx complete and sending more, getting an interrupt and sending more, or using DMA? Are you SPI master?

Comment: SPI runs in master mode. I am using CMSIS driver so I am not sure how this driver send. What am doing is like this:
uint16_t rx_buffer[4];
uint16_t read_command[4] = {0x8000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000};

SPIdrv->Transfer(read_command, rx_buffer, 4);

Check docs here: [link](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/Driver/html/group__spi__interface__gr.html#gaa24026b3822c10272e301f1505136ec2)

problem is the long idle time between transferring these 4 half words. 
No, I am not using DMA (I have plan to implement it) but anyhow DMA won't change the SPI idle time between each frame.

Comment: Please, show full code of your "CMSIS driver".
Also, what is core and peripheral bus clock frequency?

Answer (score -1):

You can show the code snippet for rest of people to be able to help, but anyways ı remember coming across the same problem.Here is how i reduce that extra time gap;

Use Direct Register Access instead of Functions, both for sending and flag checking.

If that also wont work, instead of flag checking you can use simple for loop for some amount of delay to keep to clock signal low enough but not much, check from ossilloscope to find the accurate iteration number.

Also make sure that no interrupt is being served while you send your message,there might be an ISR interrupting between the end of transmission and the code that pulls the CLK signal high. If you have ISRs that occur asynchronusly and big in size this is probably the case.

`SPI1->DR = (uint16_t)Data;
 while(!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_TXE));`

PS: I ve done this on Cortex-M3,no RTOS,STD Peripheral Library.

Edit: Also try with busy Flag only,thus checking EOC only `while(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_BSY);`